# global cache distribution for all edge locations - cloud front

Tags: amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

Videos are in S3 and i want to enforce all the edge locations to cache it when i requests for the first time, not just in one nearest location but in all the edge location. But i will be issuing the request via only one geo area.
  In detail, when i request for first time it should miss from cloud front, next time when i request again from another geographical region also it should hit from cache. Is it possible to enforce?
I have two machines one is EC2 instance another is my local machine. When i request same URL in both the machine both the times its miss from cloud. i want hit from cloud when i request from second machine

Comment: AWS CloudFront Edge-Cache only caches the files which are needed to be in Edge-Cache and the need is when they are requested from the Edge-Location region(not to confuse with AWS Regions), so if you want to ensure the files get Cached in specific geographic region, do the request to the Distribution from that region.

Comment: Is there a way to enforce caching in all the edge location?